# How to get a new NSArray which is the old one without the last element?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I mean get the new array simply, such as in python:

```
lst[:-1]
```

Is there any way to do it in objc?

Comment: do you mean *without* the last element?

Comment: @BenClayton yes, thank you already fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [-subArrayWithRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

```
[theOriginalArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [theOriginalArray count]-1)]
```

This is equivalent to the Python expression `lst[0:lst-1]`, which is the expanded form of your `lst[:-1]`.

Comment: thank you I know this way~  can we not use theOriginalArray twice? maybe sometimes the array is returned from a call..

Comment: @CHENZhao: No you have to use the name twice. You could store the returned value though, e.g. `NSArray* arr = [obj getArray]; NSArray* newArr = [arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [arr count]-1)];`

Comment: oh that's so sad.. compare to python way this is kind of complex I think:(